Gradle could not find dependency ${project.groupId}:feign-jarxrs3:13.3
I am trying to use org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2023.0.3
and somehow gradle is not able to gather weird dependency as the error said as below:

Dependency tree looks like this:

I do not understand why is it ${project.groupId} instead io.github.openfeign and I am not able to fix this import. Gradle constantly want to have this weird dependency.
I have following dependencies:
implementation(platform("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2023.0.3"))
implementation("io.github.openfeign:feign-jaxrs3:13.3")
implementation("io.github.openfeign:feign-jakarta:13.3")


share your build.gradle
